# Is it possible to include a plain html page in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I started working on a project without using any frameworks. Just used html/js/css and the Parse javascript SDK for my database. As I became aware of Meteor, I realized there were some cool features I could use from Meteor. Meteor uses handlebars and I'm not allowed to add script tags to my html docs. With Meteor, all scripts must be in js files. For this reason, I'm forced to rebuild my pages to work with handlebars and Meteor. Is it possible to just include a plain html page with handlebars? like with jade?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's ok to include it. If your framework requires you to use Handlebars templates and you don't need the dynamic functionality which it provides, then just put an HTML into it. If you can avoid this by using HTML directly and if it suits your needs then just use HTML, for the sake of effeciency.